# Changing folder on major upgrade

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I have a default directory for installation:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.Manufacturer) $(var.ProductName)"></Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

During installation, I allow users to change directory. If a user does change directory during major upgrade, do I have to retrieve the directory manually and set `INSTALLFOLDER` with actual path or is there a way to detect it automatically somehow?

Comment: Getting more complicated now, since I found multiple posts about how to set custom action CostFinalize, which ain't working. Every time I set action after CostFinalize, I get error "51 referring to a Directory. Therefore it must come before CostFinalize"

Comment: A major upgrade is a separate installation so if you are allowing users to change the directory—just as first time users do—you are done. I guess I don't understand your question. Do you want users doing a major upgrade to have a different experience than users doing a first installation?

Comment: When user installs upgrade of the software, I want that upgrade to go to the folder where previous version were installed. If during version 1 installation changed the directory to other than default, during upgrade files will go to default directory, and that the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make WiX installation set upgrade to the same folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55964/make-wix-installation-set-upgrade-to-the-same-folder)

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported by Windows Installer directly; I think you're looking for the ["remember property" pattern](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern). The strategy is:

1. On initial installation, save the value of `INSTALLFOLDER` to the registry in a well-known location.
2. When starting an upgrade, retrieve the value from the registry and use it.

The authoring looks like this:

```
<!-- Retrieve the property from the registry during AppSearch -->
<Property Id='REMEMBERME'>
  <RegistrySearch Id='RememberProperty'
                Root='HKCU'
                 Key='SOFTWARE\My Company\My App'
                Name='Remembered'
                Type='raw' />
</Property>

<!-- Save the value in the registry for future upgrades -->
<Component Directory='INSTALLFOLDER'>
    <RegistryValue Root='HKCU'
                    Key='SOFTWARE\My Company\My App'
                   Name='Remembered'
                  Value='[REMEMBERME]'
                   Type='string' />
</Component>
```

[Rob Mensching's blog post](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/the-wix-toolsets-remember-property-pattern) describes this in much more detail.